# Installing failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/confluent-kafka

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, apache-kafka

When I try to download `kafka` using `sudo pip3 install confluent_kafka` on `Ubuntu 14.04` I get error shown below. I have the newest version of `librdkafka` installed by `sudo apt-get install librdkafka-dev python-dev` which is required as it is written in prerequisites on [confluent-kafka-python github](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python). Any ideas why it doesn't work?

```
Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/confluent-kafka/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-no3e8l_m-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/confluent-kafka
Storing debug log for failure in /home/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: What does /home/elastic/.pip/pip.log say ? Are there any errors reported there?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. I tried installing `python3-confluent-kafka` using `apt` after installing `librdkafka`:

```
sudo apt install python3-confluent-kafka
```

If you are using python 2, you can run:

```
sudo apt install python-confluent-kafka
```

Then trying `pip3 install confluent-kafka` again. That fixed the build error and installed successfully.

Comment: I am using yum in rhel. I am not able to find "No package available" is the output. Can you guide me ?